# Safari offsetWidth on reload is wrong

Tags: javascript, css, safari

The past few weeks I've been working on a website which is live now. It can be seen here: http://www.momkai.com/

This website works fine in all browsers I tested it in except one: Safari. When I open this website in Safari 10.1 and hover over the first paragraph, this is what I see:

[image: correct behaviour]

This is correct. The first word of each line of text should be underlined. Hovering of the lines results in this styling:

[image: correct behaviour]

So far everything is going well. Now I reload the page and I see this:

[image: broken behaviour]

The underlines are way to wide! I've logged the offsetWidths and they are just completely wrong. This is the code which I use to retrieve the widths:

```
const parentParagraph = this.el.parentNode.parentNode;
let selfIndex;
let siblingUnderlineWidth;

this.underlineWidth = this.el.querySelector('.js-text-block-link-text-highlight').offsetWidth;
this.siblings = [].slice.call(parentParagraph.querySelectorAll('.js-text-block-link-text'));
this.siblingUnderlineWidths = [];

for (let sibling of this.siblings) {
  if (sibling.isSameNode(this.underline)) {
    selfIndex = this.siblings.indexOf(sibling);
  } else {
    siblingUnderlineWidth = sibling.querySelector('.js-text-block-link-text-highlight').offsetWidth;
    console.log(siblingUnderlineWidth);
    this.siblingUnderlineWidths.push(siblingUnderlineWidth);
  }
}

this.siblings.splice(selfIndex, 1);
```

I've also added two screenshots of the `console.log`'s to demonstrate how the values differ:

[image: correct values]
[image: incorrect behaviour]

I'm experiencing this behaviour in Safari 10.1 on desktop and Safari for iOS. I've no idea what's going wrong so I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

I'll be happy to provide more code if required.

Comment: I've had a look at the page, and the html and other javascript and css is just way too complicated to be "taken as granted" by not posting it in your question.  I can't read the text in your screenshots either.

Comment: I've added the links to the images to the post. If you need any more code please tell me.

Comment: @DavidWorldpeace did you figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: @StephenWatkins nope I didn't. Also couldn't found any other people who had this problem..

Comment: @DavidWorldpeace crazy. I ended up using MutationObservers :/

Comment: @StephenWatkins can you maybe share an example of your solution?

Comment: I have this occurring to me as well. One solution I tried out was wrapping whatever looks at offsetWidth or whatever offset (they're all wrong) with a `setTimeout(readOffsetFn, 100)` which works except I'm worried that depending on the situation, Safari might not have finished calculating the correct sizes at that time. The reason why I think that is because `setTimeout(readOffsetFn, 1)` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when something CSS changes after I refresh, it is usually a loading order issue.

For example I was using

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', runsWhenReady);
```

But sometimes the offsetWidth would be wrong.

Figured out this we because the CSS file wasn't fully loaded, which changes how the offsetWidth is.

Chrome and Safari handle caching differently, which is why it would be different on refresh.

So I switched to:

```
window.addEventListener('load', runsWhenReady);
```

Which only fires after everything including CSS is loaded and it solved the issue.